# Display posts based on category one after the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to show `Posts` which `belongs_to :categories` one after another.

Posts controller:

```
def index
  @posts = posts.order('created_at DESC').all
end
```

Post#index view:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <article>
    <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
    <p><%= post.content %></p>
    <span><%= post.category %><span>
  </article>
<% end %>
```

With the above example it will display all `posts` base on creation datetime.

**UPDATE**
If I had a 2 categories such as `burgers` and `sandwiches` and I wanted it to display first a burgers post then a sandwich post and then a burger post then sandwich post. So, it alternates between both categories eg.:

```
<article id="1">
 <h1>Cheese Burger<h1>
 <p>Content...</p>
 <span>Burgers category<span>
</article>

<article id="2">
 <h1>Ham Sandwich<h1>
 <p>Content...</p>
 <span>Sandwiches category<span>
</article>

<article id="3">
 <h1>Chicken Burger<h1>
 <p>Content...</p>
 <span>Burgers category<span>
</article>

<article id="4">
 <h1>Tomato Sandwich<h1>
 <p>Content...</p>
 <span>Sandwiches category<span>
</article>
```

Comment: +1 for the question..

Comment: write algorithm for Round Robin scheduling and fill an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't how you can do such a thing in SQL, so I'll show how you can do it in Ruby code. Unfortunately you need to do two queries. One to get the burgers and one to get the sandwiches. Then we'll use Ruby to alternate between them:

```
burgers = Post.joins(:category).where(:categories => { :name => 'Burgers' })
sandwiches = Post.joins(:category).where(:categories => { :name => 'Sandwiches' })

@posts = if burgers.size > sandwiches.size
  burgers.zip(sandwiches)
else
  sandwiches.zip(burgers)
end.flatten.compact
```

This code uses [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) to "weave" `burgers` and `sandwiches` into one array. `zip` results in nested arrays, so we'll call [`flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) on the result to make the array flat. Finally we use [`compact`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact) to get rid of any `nil` values in the array.

Comment: Thanks Mischa, I'm getting Mysql2::Error: Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous error. Otherwise, if I remove the created_at DESC it loads but not in category order. Not the alternating [burgers], [sandwiches] posts

Comment: try `categories.created_at`...but that wont help with alternating categories

Comment: What if he has more than one categories?

Comment: @stevanity - what do you mean? According to the question post belongs to category, so a post won't have more than one category. And he is talking about burgers and sandwiches specifically, not any other categories. So, I don't understand your remark. Please explain.

Comment: Quotion Him: `UPDATE If I had a 2 categories such as burgers and sandwiches`. He gave these two as examples. What if he had burgers, sandwiches, chicken, soft drinks, etc? And he wanted to display all of them alternatively? I just wanna know the solution thats all :) He said 'if' he had sandwiches and burgers.

Comment: Mischa, thank you for patience and taking the time to explain zip, flatten, and compact. I'm looking into more detail how these methods work to get a better understanding. I didn't know you could attach a method call at the end of a condition eg. end.flatten.compact thanks again. I owe you a burger and a sandwich!

Comment: @stevanity looking at the Ruby doc and what Mischa said, the zip method along with the flatten and compact will help you out. You could do something like burgers.zip(sandwiches, drinks).flatten.compact. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

need to change your association in Post model.

```
belongs_to :category
```

Then Posts controller:

```
@posts = Post.includes([:category]).order('categories.name ASC').all
```

Comment: Thanks Bachan, it seems I have the same problem where it's not displaying a sandwich post then a burgers post alternating between both.